# Show that if $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, then so is $f^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> > Show that if $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, then so is $f^2$.

I was not able to get too far:

$f$ is differentiable: $\Delta f(x,y) = f_x(x,y) h + f_y(x,y) k + \epsilon(h,k) \sqrt{h^2+k^2}$, such that $\lim\limits_{(h,k)\to(0,0)} \epsilon(h,k)=0$ (Notation: $\Delta f=f(x+h,y+k)-f(x,y)$).

$f^2$ is differentiable if $\exists A,B \in \mathbb R$ such that $\Delta f^2 = A h + B k + \alpha \sqrt{h^2+k^2}$.

I need to show that $\lim\limits_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\alpha(h,k) = 0$.
$$\alpha = \frac{\Delta f^2 -A h-B k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$
Hint on how to continue?

I tried to set $A=2f_x \cdot f ,~B=2 f_y \cdot f$ and write $\Delta f^2 = \Delta f \cdot \left[f(x+h,y+k)+f(x,y)\right]$, but that didn't help so much either.

Comment: Just to be clear you want to show it's second derivative exists/differentiable?

Comment: Yes. $f$ is differentiable, I want to show that $f^2$ is differentiable.

Comment: Just to be clear you want to show it's second derivative exists/differentiable? Or rather the product of f with itself, that seems to make more sense.

Comment: Sorry can you explain the exponent 2. Often it means nth derivative but I think it means square here.

Comment: oops... I didn't read your first comment right. The latter, i.e. to show $f \cdot f$ is differetiable.

Comment: Ok thanks. I was just a little confused on that.

Comment: It seems more fun to prove the product rule for $fg$ then apply the case $f=g$. I've never understood the attraction to problems like this which make so much effort towards a solution which could well be replaced with a general theorem which covers this problem and so much more. But, to each his own I suppose...

Comment: This is a special case of the product rule to show what the derivative is then show that the existence of $f'$ leads to the desired conclusion.

Comment: Also, if you prove that $f^2$ is differentiable, then you have that $\frac{(f+g)^2-f^2-g^2}{2}=fg$ is differentiable, so it may be uset to give a tricky proof

Comment: I think Rudin does something like that to shof that $f, g$ integrable $\Rightarrow$ $fg$ integrable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\left|f^2(x+h,y+k) - f^2(x,y) - 2f(x,y)Df(x,y)(h,k) \right| \\ . \\ = \left|\{f(x+h,y+k) - f(x,y)\} \, \{f(x+h,y+k) + f(x,y)\} \,  - \,2f(x,y)Df(x,y)(h,k) \right| \\ . \\ \leqslant |f(x+h,y+k) - f(x,y)- Df(x,y)(h,k)|\,\,\{ |f(x,y)| + |f(x+h,y +k)| \} \\ \\ + \,\, |Df(x,y)(h,k)|\,\,|f(x+h,y+k) - f(x,y)|$$

Using the fact that $f$ is differentiable and must be continuous and bounded in a neighborhood of $(x,y)$ and the linear operator $(h,k) \mapsto Df(x,y)(h,k)$ is bounded show that the RHS is of order $o(\sqrt{h^2 + k^2})$ as $(h,k) \to (0,0)$.

Basically each term on the RHS is something that goes to zero times something that is bounded as $(h,k) \to (0,0).$